# nservicebus3: SagaPersister No Current Session

Tags: nservicebus

We are introducing nservicebus 3 and saga support in our application. We have configured the nhibernate saga persister as follows:

```
  <NHibernateSagaPersisterConfig>
    <NHibernateProperties>
      <add Key="connection.provider" Value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
      <add Key="connection.driver_class" Value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
      <add Key="dialect" Value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
      <add Key="connection.connection_string_name" Value="TeamGameServiceDB"/>      
    </NHibernateProperties>
  </NHibernateSagaPersisterConfig>

    public void InitializeServiceBus(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

        Configure.With()
            .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.ImplementsTheInterface(typeof (IMessage)))
            .Log4Net()
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsolationLevel(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
            .UnicastBus()
            .Sagas()
            .NHibernateSagaPersister();
    }
```

When the saga is about to be persisted I get an exception saying "No Session is bound to the current context". I've browsing through the nservicebus.nhibernate project and I can't figure out who is responsible for setting the current session used by the SagaPersistor (the saga persistor uses ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()). The session factory configured by the nhibernate saga persister is set up to use the "NHibernate.Context.ThreadStaticSessionContext" which implies that something in the nservicebus stack should assign this. Can anyone help me in shedding some light on how I can get the ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession() to be assigned? The saga which is about to be persisted is initiated from a bus.SendLocal message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the NHibernate UnitOfWork that is included in the NServiceBus.NHibernate.dll

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/nhibernate/UnitOfWork/NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.NHibernate.Config/ConfigureNHibernateUnitOfWork.cs